# transcribe a 7sec clip?

Tags: translation

I have a very short clip of three young women giving a holiday greeting in Korean. https://www.dropbox.com/s/3q5d92amtcs3orn/translate.mp4?dl=0

I know they're saying something along the lines of "have a great new year," but I can't quite nail the exact Korean. Can anybody help me with the exact phrase they're saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "연말 잘 보내세요." [yeonmal jal bonaeseyo]

Which literally translates to "Have a nice end of the year."